# Selenium Webdriver :To enter an element into ul li text box

Tags: java, textbox, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to access an input field here, but I am getting an error message stating :

Element currently not visible. 
When I try to type an element into the input field using sendkeys method, it still doesn't result into anything. The html code of the element is below :

```
<ul class="tagedit-list "><li class="tagedit-listelement tagedit-listelement-new"><input type="text" name="tag[]" value="" id="tagedit-input" maxlength="30" disabled="disabled" class="tagedit-input-disabled ui-autocomplete-input" dir="ltr" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true"><tester style="position: absolute; top: -9999px; left: -9999px; width: auto; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; white-space: nowrap;"></tester><span id="addTagLabel">Add a Tag<span></span></span></li></ul>
```

Please guide me on what could possibly be going wrong here. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give us the code, and we may be able to help. The issue is that the element is not visible, you could possibly use an [Explicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp).

Here is some sample code in Java to see if it may nudge you in the right direction,

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, seconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(id));
```

If not, could you give more information as to why the element is not visible, page loading, etc?
Another possibility maybe to use [JavaScriptExecutor](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html).

Comment: It may also be helpful to make a utilty class, where you can make these static methods, and call them much easier(you will be using waits alot).

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the code you have tried or the link.

It is occurring because the element you are trying to interact with is not
visible.
To solve this issue you need to do something to make the element visible
first. When you test it manually check with inspect element which makes the element visible.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution guys....

The visibility of the text box was hidden so i used jquery to make that element visible and also to enter a text into that element.... Now its working fine

Code i used was

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$J(\".tagedit-list li.tagedit-listelement-new input.tagedit-input-disabled\").css(\"display\", \"block\");"); 

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$J(\".tagedit-list li.tagedit-listelement-new input.tagedit-input-disabled\").val(\"test\");");

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$J(\"#addTag\").css(\"display\", \"block\");");

driver.findElement(By.id("addTag")).click();
```

Thank you....guys